# is there a way to numerically find the IEEE 754 conversion of a floating decimal

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, ieee-754

So I just made a float binary to float decimal converter. Now i'm attempting to do the opposite. My goal is to take a floating decimal and convert it to the IEEE 754 format. I've seen the methodology done on paper but when trying to implement it into code i'm running into a lot of issues when trying to manipulate the program's input, which is a char array. I'd show my code but it's extremely wrong and extremely bulky. In short, my method was to:

```
1. find the signed bit (negative/non-negative)
2. separate the whole number and fraction
3. find the whole numbers binary equivalent
3. find the fractional numbers binary pattern (multiplying fraction by 2 repeatedly)
4. recombine whole and fractional parts
5. find the exponent associated with the scientific notation form of of the combined values
6. add 127(bias) to exponent to find "exponent number"
7. convert exponent number to binary
8. finally, combine all these different values together as such: 

signed bit char -> exponent bits array -> whole number binary array from [1] to [n] -> fractional numbers binary pattern array
```

which should theoretically give you the IEEE format. I'm running into a lot of errors when attempting to use this method, mainly with string manipulation, memory errors, etc. So my question is, is there a simpler way of accomplishing this rather than having multiple binary char array's and then combining them? Is it possible to atof() the initial input and work my way down from there? Any tips on making this process easier would be much appreciated.

Examples:

- Input (from command line)

  ./file 250
- output

  11000011011110100000000000000000
- Input

  ./file -0.78
- output

  10111111010001111010111000010100

Note* i'm to output 32 bits with a bias of 127

Comment: Do you know about the [`ldexp`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ldexp) function?  It will do most of the work for you.  (But if you want to do everything yourself, the hard way, it's not for you.)

Comment: *Is it possible to atof() the initial input* — If you're willing to use `atof`, it will do *all* the work for you!

Comment: You might need to be a little more clear on what your desired input and output formats are.  Are you trying to take a decimal number, represented as a string, and construct the equivalent IEEE-754 single-precision floating-point number, having 32 bits?

Comment: Do you know how to write `atoi`?  It's reasonably straightforward to start there, and extend it into a serviceable implementation of `atof`.  Are you allowed to use `float` arithmetic?

Comment: You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306289) and its answers interesting.

Comment: Mike Quinnn, The 2 step 3s may involve hundreds of bit.  `long long` is not sufficient - especially if one wants a correctly rounded answer.

Comment: "So my question is, is there a simpler way of accomplishing this rather than having multiple binary char array's and then combining them?" --> No, if you want the best conversion.,  Yes, if you tolerate a conversion that may be wrong in many least bits.

Comment: Can you assume that `float` and `double` *variables* are natively represented in IEEE 754, or do you want a fully cross-platform solution that returns IEEE 754 even if the native floating-point format is something different?

Comment: @SteveSummit Could you expand on how atof() would "do all the work" for me? As far as I understand atof() will merely convert convert the decimal to a float. Ultimately I will need to convert said float in IEEE binary format. Also, yes I'm familiar with atoi() and what exactly is meant by float arithmatic?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'll include an example I/O in the original post.

Comment: @MikeQuinnn  From where I sit, it's just a matter of interpretation.  `float f = atof("-250")` will give you a 4-byte `float` value `f` which, if you were able to look at it in hex, would already contain `0xc37a0000` or, in binary, `0b11000011011110100000000000000000`.  Similarly, `atof("-0.78")` would give you `0xbf47ae14`, or `0b10111111010001111010111000010100`.

Comment: So if you're allowed to use `atof`, your only remaining task is to figure out how to see the hexadecimal representation of a `float` variable (which Andrew's answer contains a clue about), or then, how to see that hexadecimal value in binary.

Comment: But if your task is to take a number like -250 or -0.78 and compute the sign, significand, and exponent values yourself, and then assemble them into an IEEE-754 single-precision floating-point value, calling `atof` to do all the work might be considered nonsporting.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this successfully in production code:

```
// endian issues???
union {
    float f;
    unsigned u;
} Rx_PWR0;
```