# What is the Best Way to Parse Floats?

Tags: parsing, floating-point

Here's a naïve way of parsing floats in C that does not check for extraneous numerical forms or overflow:

```c
double parse_number(const char *str)
{
    double ret = 0.0, denom = 0.0, mag = 1.0;

    for (; isdigit(*str); str++) {
        ret = ret * 10.0 + (*str - '0');
    }

    if (*str != '.') {
        return ret;
    }

    /* Basic attempt to minimize error when adding the fractional part */
    for (; isdigit(*str); str++, mag *= 10.0) {
        denom = denom * 10.0 + (*str - '0');
    }

    return ret + denom / mag;
}
```

While this works, I'm sure that there is a minor error when translating from text to a number, due to the imprecision of floats. Is there a better way to parse floats so there isn't any error (or the error is minimal)? Also, is there an IEEE-compliant way to parse floats?

I am asking more from a theoretical standpoint than a pracitcal one, so I'm not considering `atof` and the like.

Comment: Correctly converting a string to a floating point number is an extremely difficult operation and probably not worth attempting unless you are experienced in analyzing numerical error. As a starting point, though, you should examine the implementation of `atof()` in your standard library.

Comment: (Your approach is actually decent, but overflows with too long a mantissa, and doesn't round properly.)

Comment: Sample C++ code to convert decimal numerals to floating-point is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58309048/298225). And that is the easy but inefficient method—it is written to demonstrate the elementary concepts, including correct rounding.

Comment: Re “is there an IEEE-compliant way to parse floats?”: Parsing is an operation like any other. It converts a numeral (a string containing a representation of a numeral) to a floating-point value. The usual standards for floating-point operations apply: The result should be the representable value that is closest to the input value in the direction selected by the rounding method being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the Best Way to Parse Floats?

Use `strtof()`, available in the standard C library, to parse `float`s.
Use `strtod()`, available in the standard C library, to parse `double`s.

---

OP code troubles include:

- No support for negative numbers including -0.0.  This omission makes the code unsatisfactory for general use.  I am suprised OP's code does not handle "-123".
- No support for the positive sign.
- No support for optional leading whitespace - something very common in *string* to `float` convertors.
- No support for infinity or Not-a-number.
- Undefined behavior (UB) when `*str < 0`.
- Accumulated errors with repeated `* 10.0` code.
- `ret + denom / mag` incur calculation errors that other forms do not.
- No support for exponential nor hexadecimal forms.
- No indication of totally failed conversion or extra non-numeric junk.
- Rounding is suspect.
- Better solutions would carry a test harness to at least perform minimal testing.

---

> Also, is there an IEEE-compliant way to parse floats?

Yes. Good solutions work with higher precision than the result target.  Great solitons work can readily return the best IEE compliant result every time, even with extreme zero about before/after and large exponents.

Note: It is more like parsing *text* to convert to a `float`.

Comment: Since the OP is using `double`, it should actually be `strtod()`. It should also be noted that `strtof()`, `strtod()` and `strtold()` are locale-sensitive, which may be an issue. Also note that in locales where the `-` character is regarded as whitespace (as currently allowed by ISO C), negative numbers would be parsed as positive numbers because the minus character would be regarded as leading whitespace (if `.` is regarded as whitespace, this is problematic too).

Comment: @vinc17 "in locales where the - character is regarded as whitespace (as currently allowed by ISO C)," --> interesting pedantic thought.  Know of any non-theoretical examples?

Comment: Not under Linux, where the character classes of the ASCII characters do not seem to depend on the current locale.